# FOSCKEditorBundle sometimes works and sometimes not , conflict with bootsnav.js

Tags: javascript, symfony, symfony4, webpack-encore

I'm using Symfony 4, and webPack encore bundle. I have a bizarre issue with Fosckeditorbundle, **sometimes it works well** and sometimes I get an error in the console, and I should refresh the browser many times until the bundle works.

FOSCkeditor bundle is not handled with Webpack Encore but the problem comes after using Webpack Encore bundle.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getClientRect' of null
at p.getClientRect (ckeditor.js:1253)
at p.queryViewport (ckeditor.js:1253)
at new p (ckeditor.js:1238)
at a.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:1274)
at a.p (ckeditor.js:10)
at a.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:12)
at a.CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire (ckeditor.js:13)
at $.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:944)
at ckeditor.js:30
```

**EDIT:**

I have made some tests and I have found that the problem comes from **bootsnav.js**, when I remove it, I have no error.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Webpack Encore, you should use the FosCKEditorBundle with Webpack Encore.

1. Remove your CKEditor copy (not FosCKEditorBundle).
2. Re-install it *via* Webpack Encore. According to [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSCKEditorBundle/installation.html), you just have to:

   yarn add ckeditor@^4.0.0

Then in webpack config:

```js
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // ...
    .copyFiles([
        {from: './node_modules/ckeditor/', to: 'ckeditor/[path][name].[ext]', pattern: /\.(js|css)$/, includeSubdirectories: false},
        {from: './node_modules/ckeditor/adapters', to: 'ckeditor/adapters/[path][name].[ext]'},
        {from: './node_modules/ckeditor/lang', to: 'ckeditor/lang/[path][name].[ext]'},
        {from: './node_modules/ckeditor/plugins', to: 'ckeditor/plugins/[path][name].[ext]'},
        {from: './node_modules/ckeditor/skins', to: 'ckeditor/skins/[path][name].[ext]'}
    ])

;
```

Don't forget, if needed, to update your config path in fos_ckeditor.yaml:

```
fos_ck_editor:
    # ...
    base_path: "build/ckeditor"
    js_path:   "build/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"
```

This way, you will avoid js conflicts.